# Run a macro before the start of each frame/slide?

Tags: beamer

I have a macro that I want to run just before every new beamer frame. I could just a define `myframe` environment that runs the macro then starts a standard frame, but I'd rather do it differently if I can.

Beamer has neat `\AtBeginSection` functionality, but am I right in thinking there's no such analogue like `\AtBeginFrame`...

And would the situation be different if I actually wanted to do something before setting each *slide*? [Edit: I asked this last part as a [separate question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7427/215)]

Comment: Do you need to process options to frames? A patch or such a `myframe` environment would need to consider that.

Comment: Because without options, ` \g@addto@macro\frame\yourmacro` would be a possibility.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the patching facilities of `etoolbox` to patch `\frame` to do what you want.

Since `\frame` is parameterless, it'd seem like you want to do

```
\preto\frame{\foo}
```

This will cause `\foo` to happen before the frame.

If you want things to happen after all of the argument processing, it's significantly more complex because it appears that beamer follows lots of different paths. (I sort of gave up after `\beamer@@@@frame` which then sets `\beamer@howtotreatframe` in a bunch of different ways depending on some conditions.)

Here's a simple example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\frame{\typeout{Starting new frame.}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
asdf
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
asdf
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you give an example of how I might patch the frame enviroment to execute the `\foo` macro before each frame?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like the ideal job for `\BeforeBeginEnvironment`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{frame}{\typeout{Starting new frame.}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
asdf
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
asdf
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Old post, but I’ve been looking for something alike for some time and came up with a nice solution for this without any extra package so I wanted to share it.

For each *frame*, not slide, you could put in your preamble something like:

```
\let\oldframe\frame
\def\frame{\yourmacro\oldframe}
```

The point is that `\frame` macro is very fragile and it parses the options that comes after it so appending something to `\frame` will not work. This will let you *prepend* something to `\frame` without messing with the usual behaviour of the macro.

Also, note that this will affect both `\frame{...}` command and `\begin{frame}...\end{frame}` environment.