# Run macro before each slide in beamer

Tags: beamer, etoolbox

Following on from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7126/215), is there an easy way to call a macro before each *slide*? So that question answers how to get at each frame, but I want finer control...

I want a macro that sets a counter to the current fraction of slides we've go through so far. I can't get at it through etoolbox's patching controls, because the slides are controlled more internally than that...

Comment: What are you going to do with this counter? (It can't be a counter if it's a fraction, but that's not the point)  Can you not just compute it at the time of placement?

Comment: I want it to change the colour of the structure elements, so "time of placement" _is_ the start of the slide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcounter{myctr}
\renewcommand\themyctr{frame~\arabic{myctr}}
\makeatletter
\def\beamer@checkframetitle{\stepcounter{myctr}%
  \@ifnextchar\bgroup\beamer@inlineframetitle{}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{foo}{\themyctr}
foo
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{foo}{\themyctr}
foo
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{foo}{\themyctr}
foo
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{foo}{\themyctr}
foo
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works. You could make your MWE neater by adding a couple of `\pause` s to show what it can do within a frame! Could you explain how it works? Is `\beamer@checkframetitle` the first thing beamer does with a frame?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me!

```
  \makeatletter
  \g@addto@macro{\frame}{Test}
  \makeatother
```

`\g@addto@macro` is defined in `LaTeX`, etoolbox has an exact clone, but I can't remember the exact command:)

Comment: That runs something at the beginning of each *frame,* but Seamus is asking for something at the beginning of each *slide*.  (A slide is one of the overlays on a frame.)

Comment: @Matthew is right, this doesn't do what I want it to. The etoolbox version is, I think, `\appto`