# Beamer, notes, and bibliography

Tags: beamer, biblatex, notes

I would like to create notes for a set of slides, but I have problem with my long bibliography.
Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeameroption{show only notes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{beamer.bib}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\makeatletter
\def\beamer@framenotesbegin{% at beginning of slide
    \gdef\beamer@noteitems{}%
    \gdef\beamer@notes{{}}% used to be totally empty.
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    FOO \\[10cm]
    BAR
\end{frame}
\appendix
\begin{frame}
    \cite{Stack1,Stack2,Stack3,Stack4,Stack5}.
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    \printbibliography
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

With beamer.bib looking similar to:

```
@MISC{Stack1, 
  author = {Caesar, Gaius J.}, 
  title = {My long title}, 
  year = {2005}, 
  addendum={Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.} 
}
@MISC{Stack2, 
  author = {Caesar, Gaius J.}, 
  title = {My long title}, 
  year = {2005}, 
  addendum={Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.} 
}
@MISC{Stack3, 
  author = {Gaius J., Caesar}, 
  title = {My long title}, 
  year = {2005}, 
  addendum={Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.} 
}
@MISC{Stack4, 
  author = {Caesar, Gaius J.}, 
  title = {My long title}, 
  year = {2005}, 
  addendum={Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.} 
}
@MISC{Stack5, 
  author = {Gaius J., Caesar}, 
  title = {My long title}, 
  year = {2005}, 
  addendum={Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.} 
}
```

I used the answer to this question: [Run macro on each frame in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11708/run-macro-on-each-frame-in-beamer) to generate as many frames in my notes as in my slides. However, if you look at the last note, the bibliography doesn't show up, and as it spans over two frames (if you uncomment the second line `\setbeameroption{show only notes}`), I don't have the same number of frames in both documents.

Any workaround ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\cite` commands on the frames are ignored when you compile with `show only notes`, resulting in an empty bibliography.

Are you sure you want only the notes?

A quick workaround for this would be to compile with `\setbeameroption{show notes}`, so all frames and notes make it into the output document and then post-process with `pdftk` (or some other PDF toolkit) to extract only the even pages from the resulting PDF:

```
pdftk slidesandnotes.pdf cat even output notes.pdf
```

However, I usually prefer to have the notes together with an image of the slide on each page, so my attempt would be to post-process instead with:

```
pdfnup --no-landscape --nup 1x2 --scale 0.9 --twoside --offset '0.8cm 0cm'
```

Ths would result in a portrait-oriented PDF with the slides content in the upper half and the notes in the lower half.

Comment: Alright! I was using `show only notes` to create two separate documents that I could use with Skim. Anyway, your `pfdnup` solution is great, just a quick question though, do you know if there is a way to generate `note`s that are not as big as a normal frames ? For example, I would like to generate a PDF with `\setbeameroption{show notes}` where notes frames are a third of the width of the actual frames. (I don't care if the scaling is done within the `.tex` or with `pfdnup`)

Comment: @BigDawg: Do you want to change only the width, but not the height of the note frames? Or do you just want to scale everything "as is" by 0.3?

Comment: just the width -- or the height --, as I still want the text inside my notes to be readable (but since there is not a lot of text, I would like to decrease the height -- or the width).

Comment: @BigDawg: Does this mean that the (physical) PDF page size can remain as is (128x96mm) and you want to have larger margins?

Comment: I don't think so, it means I want to have odd pages of size 128x96mm and even pages of size 90x96mm (just random figures here for the width but I think you get the point)

Comment: @BigDawg: Hmm, this is probably not so easy ==> deserves a question on its own.

Comment: Old thread, I know... :) But `\printbibliography` is empty even if there's a `\cite` in the notes. Is this the expected behaviour?