# References when using only notes in beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex, bibliographies, notes

I use notes in my slides, what's good for my lectures. I also like to pass the notes to the students (with `handout` and `show only notes`).

When using `biblatex`'s `\printbibliography`, however, the references are not processed correctly for the notes.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setbeameroption{show only notes}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@book{knuth1979tex,
    author = "Donald E. Knuth",
    title = "Tex and Metafont, New Directions in Typesetting",
    year = "1979",
    publisher = "American Mathematical Society and Digital Press",
    address = "Stanford"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
        Citation: \textcite{knuth1979tex}\\
    Reference:\printbibliography

    \note{
        Citation: \textcite{knuth1979tex}\\
        Reference:\printbibliography
    }
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Unlike thread [60671](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60671/beamer-notes-and-bibliography), I **do** have `\cite`s in the notes.

`Biber` works successfully (returns 0) and the entry is present in the `bbl` file:

```
...
\entry{knuth1979tex}{book}{}
  \name{author}{1}{}{%
    {{hash=fcbea740aeb72b8e941e0d4aa9f6a9c6}{%
       family={Knuth},
       familyi={K\bibinitperiod},
       given={Donald\bibnamedelima E.},
...
```

In fact, the `bbl` file is not used when `show only notes` is used, ignoring the `\cite` and failing to generate the references. Here's the log:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'knuth1979tex' on page 1 undefined on input line 30.
```

Is there a way to get the bibliography working when generating only the notes?

Comment: Very good question! I hope you will get an answer to your question. In the mean time maybe the workaround from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60688/36296 could help

Comment: AFAICS `biblatex` does not work within `\note`. Its citation requests simply don't make it to the `.aux` and `.bcf` files. Indeed no command is allowed to write to the `.aux` files in `\note` (within `\if@filesw` yields false) and with `show only notes` file writing is disabled globally. Whether that is necessary or useful for a `beamer` note I can't say.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained in the comments, the problem for `biblatex` is that `beamer`'s `show only notes` option issues `\nofiles`. That command usually suppresses writing of `.aux` files and similar, but with `biblatex` it actually also inhibits loading of the `.bbl` file (it should not do that and that might be considered a bug in `biblatex` which will be resolved in the upcoming version 3.12 https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/9ccd26105820eb11c7c38302123e9a0408c0189d).

As a quick workaround you can tell `beamer` not to call `\nofiles` in `show only notes`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
\defbeameroption{show only notes}[]%
{
  \beamer@notestrue
  \beamer@notesnormalsfalse
}
\makeatother

\setbeameroption{show only notes}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \textcite{sigfridsson}
  \printbibliography

  \note{
    \textcite{worman}
    \printbibliography
  }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Great answer!

Comment: Perfect. This workaround will do the job while we wait for the new version. Also, you live, you learn: I didn't know about  `biblatex-examples.bib` and have just learned about the package `filecontents` :-)

Comment: My savior! Thank you!