# add notes in beamer for all pages

Tags: notes, beamer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Run macro on each frame in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11708/run-macro-on-each-frame-in-beamer)

I'm creating a presentation using beamer, and I want it to put the slides in the odd pages, and in the even pages put the notes. But I want it to add a notes page even when the slide doesn't have a \note command. If I use [notes=show], it only adds the notes pages after the slides with \note commands. I want to have the page with the reduced slide after each slide.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.