# Beamer section page and show notes for every page

Tags: beamer, sectioning, notes

I want to have a notepage for every single page, even if it will be empty. This I accomplished with the help of this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11724/36296

But now, I have the problem, that I also want to have a special page at the beginning of a new section. But when I try to add a `\note{...}` after a new section started, there is an additional empty notepage.

**Edit:**

The goal I am trying to achieve is that after the section page the note page with "notes to section page" follows immediately without an empty notepage first.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeameroption{show notes}

% notepage for every slide, even if empty
\makeatletter 
\def\beamer@framenotesbegin{%   
    \gdef\beamer@noteitems{}%   
    \gdef\beamer@notes{{}}%  
}
\makeatother

% section page
\AtBeginSection{%
    \begin{frame}
        \insertsection
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        slide with note
        \note{testnote}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        test with empty note
    \end{frame}

    \section{Section with note}
    \note{notes to section page}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what the effect you're trying to achieve? It seems that you're trying to get rid of an extra page, but which page?

Comment: @KevinC Thanks for having a look, I updated the question

Comment: Is using `\usepackage{pgfpages}\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}` an alternative? This creates a double-width PDF document showing the frame on the left and the notes on the right (ensuring that each frame is followed by exactly one note page, without the need for [your current hack](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11724/3323)). However, this setup may not be compatible with your presentation software. More information on the option can be found in [the `beamer` manual, section 19.3](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf#subsection.19.3).

Comment: @diabonas Your idea solved my problem. Can you please turn your comment into an answer, so that I can accept and upvote it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [beamer option `show notes on second screen`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf#subsection.19.3), which creates a double-width PDF document showing the actual frame on the left and the notes on the right. It ensures that each frame is followed by exactly one note page, so it doesn't need the manual solution described in [Run macro on each frame in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11724/3323). This approach relies on the package [`pgfpages`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf#section.58), which has to be loaded manually before using the option:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}

% section page
\AtBeginSection{%
    \begin{frame}
        \insertsection
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        slide with note
        \note{testnote}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        test with empty note
    \end{frame}

    \section{Section with note}
    \note{notes to section page}

\end{document}
```

[image: page of a beamer document, showing a section page and the corresponding note page side-by-side]

Answer (score 2):

[diabonas](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141195/36296) answered exactly the question I had asked. But unfortunately his approach caused follow up problems when creating print versions with multiples frames per page (see [follow up question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141194/36296))

A possibility to avoid these problems is to define an own command for the section pages

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeameroption{show notes}

% notepage for every slide, even if empty
\makeatletter 
\def\beamer@framenotesbegin{%   
    \gdef\beamer@noteitems{}%   
    \gdef\beamer@notes{{}}%  
}
\makeatother

% section page
\newcommand{\mysection}[2]{%
        \section{#1}
    \begin{frame}
        \insertsection
        \note{#2}
    \end{frame}
}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{8 on 1}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        slide with note
        \note{testnote}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        test with empty note
    \end{frame}

    \mysection{Section with note}{notes to section page}

    \mysection{Section without notes}

\end{document}
```

[image]