# Creating a handout with the notes on a second screen

Tags: beamer, notes, pgfpages

How can I print slides and their accompanying note pages from a second screen as a handout? I try to accomplish this look:

[image]

(preferably 3 slides and their 3 note pages per page, the spaces between the slides are not important).

---

Now when using `\pgfpagesuselayout{8 on 1}` some slides are missing and the positioning is completely wrong:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}

\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen} 

\pgfpagesuselayout{8 on 1}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=gray}

\begin{document}

    \fontsize{60}{64}\selectfont

    \begin{frame}
         Slide 1
        \note{\fontsize{60}{64}\selectfont Note 1}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        Slide 2
        \note{\fontsize{60}{64}\selectfont Note 2}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        Slide 3
        \note{\fontsize{60}{64}\selectfont Note 3}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If possible I would like to keep `\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}`, because of this [Beamer section page and show notes for every page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141038/beamer-section-page-and-show-notes-for-every-page) question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would just use `pdfnup` for the task:

```
pdfnup --nup 1x3 --no-landscape --scale 0.9 --delta "0 1cm" --no-tidy slides.pdf
```

yields a file `slides-nup.pdf` that with the intended layout:

[image]

The `pdfnup` shell script is part of the [`pdfjam` collection](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam/), which is included in most Linux distros. For MacOS it is available via MacPorts, fink, or brew. On Windows, it should work together with cygwin or mingw, but I haven't tested that.

However, as `pdfjam` is just a wrapper around `pdflatex` and the [`pdfpages` LaTeX package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/), you could as well employ `pdflatex` for the task directly (using an extra LaTeX document):

```
\batchmode
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
  \includepdfmerge[nup=1x3,scale=0.9,delta=0 1cm]{slides.pdf,-}
\end{document}
```

**A solution for a reusable template:**

For a reusable, platform-independent template using only `pdflatex` and no external tools, we could improve the above to a generic handout-from-slides generator.

The following assumes that your presentation template is named with a `-slides` suffix, that is,  `<presentation>-slides.tex`, which will then compile to a file `<presentation>-slides.pdf`. The following code should be provided as `<presentation>-handout.tex`.

If one compiles `<presentation>-handout.tex`, it does the follwing:

- Checks if `<presentation>-slides.pdf` does exists and prints an error if not
- Generates `<presentation>-handout.pdf` with the respective nup setting.
- Checks if `<presentation>-slides.pdf` was recent, that is, not older than `<presentation>-slides.tex`. Otherwise, it prints a warning.

Users just need to rename `<presentation>-slides.tex` and `<presentation>-handout.tex` accordingly and compile them in the "right" order (which is anyway the "natural" oder, as handout production usually comes last...)

```
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141194/creating-a-handout-with-the-notes-of-a-second-screen/141294
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

% We assume that this file is named
%
%    <presentation>-handout.tex
%
% and that the actual material stems from a file
%
%    <presentation>-slides.pdf
%
% which itself is compiled out of the source file
% 
%    <presentation>-slides.tex
%

\newcommand{\jobbasename}{}
\newcommand{\setjobbasename}{%
  \def\split##1-##2!!!{\def\jobbasename{##1}}%
  \expandafter\split\jobname!!!%
}

% after: \jobbasename is <presentation>
\setjobbasename 

\begin{document}
  % Check if <presentation>.pdf does exist, otherwise typeout an error message
  \IfFileExists{\jobbasename-slides.pdf}{%
    % Include the material
    \includepdf[nup=1x3,scale=0.9,delta=0 1cm,pages=-]{\jobbasename-slides.pdf}
    % Check if <presentation.pdf> is older than <presentation.tex> and typeout a warning
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\pdffilemoddate{\jobbasename-slides.pdf}}{\pdffilemoddate{\jobbasename-slides.tex}}<0%
      \typeout{}
      \typeout{WARNING: \jobbasename-slides.pdf seems to be out of date!}
      \typeout{\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space Consider recompiling \jobbasename-slides.tex.}
      \typeout{}
    \fi
  }{%
    \typeout{}
    \typeout{ERROR: \jobbasename-slides.pdf not found!}
    \typeout{\space\space\space\space\space\space\space You need to compile \jobbasename-slides.tex first.}
    \typeout{}
  }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This would certainly give the desired result. Since I am working on a template for my institute, I still hope for a solution easier to handle for the individual user. In case no easier answer comes up soon, I will of course accept yours!

Comment: @samcarter: Please see extended answer