# How to make \cleardoublepage still valid in beamer?

Tags: beamer, clearpage

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\def\cleardoublepage{...}  <-- how to do this ?
\begin{document}
\frame{this is page 1}
\frame{this is page 2}
\cleardoublepage
\frame{this is page 3} %<-- show in page 3
\cleardoublepage
\frame{this is page 5}  %<-- show in page 5
\end{document}
```

How to write the \def ... ?

Comment: `\cleardoublepage` is used in double sided documents to force the placement of remaining floats (figures,tables etc) and finish everything untill start a new page (ususally a new chapter) from the upcoming empty odd page... So, in beamer something like this would not have an effect. Please be more specific on what you want to achieve...

Comment: i want \frame{this is page 3}  and  \frame{this is  page 5} on odd pages, because i will use "view -> double page" mode show sth, perhaps blank on page 4 but some notes on page 6

Comment: \just use an empty \frame{} between page 3 and page 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You indicated in comments, that you want to use these additional pages for things like notes. The good news is that beamer already has a mechanism for notes, which you could use:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeameroption{show notes}

\setbeamertemplate{note page}{\insertnote} % <- make the notes pages empty, otherwise it will show a preview of the frame 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
this is page 1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
this is page 2
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
this is page 3
\note{~}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
this is page 5
\note{notes on page 6}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: but i dont want to add “\note{~}” manually

Comment: @ZenoShuai If you want to add the notes pages automatically, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11724/36296