# Placing beamer buttons - automatic placement?

Tags: beamer, button

I have for a long time been using a code to place beamer buttons on a slide that is very inefficient as it requires me to specify exactly the position of each button. Below a MWE of the code I am using.

Is there anyway that I can avoid specifying the position of the button? I.e. they would just line up automatically from the bottom right hand corner to the left ...

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}%
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ mathrsfs }
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{textpos}

\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{140,140,172}
\definecolor{bluegreen}{RGB}{173,173,224}
\definecolor{lightbluegreen}{RGB}{204,0,51}
\definecolor{cyan}{RGB}{30,24,83}


\usepackage[beamer,customcolors]{hf-tikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{hl/.style={
    set fill color=black!00,
    set border color=red!80!black,
  },
}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,arrows,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Button Positions}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node[shift={(-0.9cm,0.5cm)}]() at (current page.south east){%
        \hyperlink{Link6}{\beamerbutton{First link}}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node[shift={(-2.7cm,0.5cm)}]() at (current page.south east){%
        \hyperlink{Link5}{\beamerbutton{Second link}}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node[shift={(-4.8cm,0.5cm)}]() at (current page.south east){%
        \hyperlink{Link4}{\beamerbutton{Third link longer name}}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node[shift={(-6.4cm,0.5cm)}]() at (current page.south east){%
        \hyperlink{Link3}{\beamerbutton{Fourth link}}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node[shift={(-7.5cm,0.5cm)}]() at (current page.south east){%
        \hyperlink{Link2}{\beamerbutton{Fifth link}}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node[shift={(-9.00cm,0.5cm)}]() at (current page.south east){%
        \hyperlink{Link1}{\beamerbutton{Sixth link}}};
        \end{tikzpicture}    
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node[shift={(-1.35cm,0.95cm)}]() at (current page.south east){%
        \hyperlink{Link7}{\beamerbutton{Seventh Link}}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way using `chains`. (I removed all packages that are not related to the problem but left `babel` to show that you also may want to use the Ti*k*Z library of the same name.)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}%
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Button Positions}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,start chain=going left,node
distance=1ex]
\foreach \X/\Y [count=\Z] in {First/6,Second/5,Third/4,Fourth/3,%
    Fifth/2,Sixth/1,Seventh/7}
{\ifnum\Z=1
\path ([yshift=1em]current page.south east) node[on chain,anchor=south east]
{\hyperlink{Link\Y}{\beamerbutton{\X~link}}};
\else
\path node[on chain]
{\hyperlink{Link\Y}{\beamerbutton{\X~link}}};
\fi}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another way is to create a command that adds a button left of the previous button. (If you think you will add so many buttons that one row is not sufficient, please let me know.)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}%
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/345082/194703
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{frame}{\FrameHasButtonfalse}
\newif\ifFrameHasButton
\newcommand{\AddButton}[3][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\ifFrameHasButton
\node[left=1em of tmpbutton] (tmpbutton)
{\hyperlink{Link#3}{\beamerbutton{#2~link}}};
\else
\path ([yshift=1em]current page.south east) 
node[anchor=south east] (tmpbutton)
{\hyperlink{Link#3}{\beamerbutton{#2~link}}};
\global\FrameHasButtontrue
\fi
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Button Positions}
\AddButton{First}{6}%
\AddButton{Second}{5}%
\AddButton{Third}{4}%
\AddButton{Fourth}{3}%
\AddButton{Fifth}{2}%
\AddButton{Sixth}{1}%
\AddButton{Seventh}{7}%
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Button Positions}
\AddButton{First}{6}%
\AddButton{Third}{4}%
\AddButton{Fifth}{2}%
\AddButton{Seventh}{7}%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow. This is great specially the second solution. Thank you very much. The second row would be a cherry on top of the cake. Thank you.

Comment: Wait, I am a bit confused, where do I actually put the links on the last piece of code?

Comment: @phdstudent I was assuming the links are all of the form `Link<number>` so you add them with `\AddButton{<label>}{<number>}` If this is not the case, you can use `\newcommand{\AddButton}[3][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\ifFrameHasButton
\node[left=1em of tmpbutton] (tmpbutton)
{\hyperlink{#3}{\beamerbutton{#2~link}}};
\else
\path ([yshift=1em]current page.south east) 
node[anchor=south east] (tmpbutton)
{\hyperlink{#3}{\beamerbutton{#2~link}}};
\global\FrameHasButtontrue
\fi
\end{tikzpicture}}`.